# Move Files up one folder level with batch script

Tags: batch-file, move, directory, directory-structure

I am a newbie in batch scripting and need your help, as all the already answered questions don't really fix my problem.

I have a folder structure that contains either a parent folder with a sub-folder and a file, parent-folder with an empty sub-folder, an empty parent-folder or an  parent folder with only a file. This is all in one main folder. So it can look like this:

```
└───Main-Folder
    ├───Parent-folder 1
    │   └───Sub-folder 1 (empty)
    ├───Parent-folder 2
    │   └───Sub-folder 2
    │           File 2
    │
    ├───Parent-folder 3
    │       File 3
    │
    └───Parent-folder 4 (empty)
```

Basically what I would need is that IF there is a file in a sub-folder it will be moved up one level to the respective parent-folder.
All empty sub-folders should be deleted.
All empty parent-folders should remain untouched.
All files already in parent-folders should remain untouched.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service, but a website for ***programmers*** from whom own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Your user lastname won't help here ;-)

Comment: Fine, then go for it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use two stacked `for /d` to

- first iterate parent `%%P` folders and a
- 2nd for the subfolders `%%S`
- The Move and RD commands output and error output is redirected to null to suppress messages

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\16\SO_51362593.cmd
@Echo off
Pushd "A:\Main-folder" || Exit /B 1
For /d %%P in (*) Do (
    For /d %%S in ("%%P\*") Do (
        Move "%%~fS\*" "%%~fP\" 2>&1>Nul
        RD /S /Q "%%~fS" 2>&1>Nul
    )
)
PopD
```

Sample `tree /f` after running the batch:

```
> tree /f
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
└───Main-Folder
    ├───Parent-folder 1
    ├───Parent-folder 2
    │       File 2
    │
    ├───Parent-folder 3
    │       File 3
    │
    └───Parent-folder 4 (empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work with your exemple :

```
REM for each parent folder in your main folder
for /F %%i in ('dir /A:d /b') DO (
    REM for each subfolder
    for /F %%j in ('dir /A:d /b "%%i"') DO (
        copy "%%i\%%j\*.*" "%%i"
        rd /s "%%i\%%j"
    )
)
```

The script must be in your main folder